# Error al abrir mi proyecto de android studio desde otra pc

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Tengo un problema desde que hice mi primera aplicación en android studio y hasta ahora no se como solucionarlo, mi problema es que cuando llevo mi proyecto a otra PC (de la universidad) aparece un error, les dejo que error que aparece

[image: AL ABRIR EL PROYECTO APARECE ESTO]

[image: DESPUES DE DARLE OK, CARGA EL PROYECTO Y APARECE ESTE ERROR]

Comment: Son dos cosas distintas: el primer problema es un aviso de que el SDK está en un directorio diferente al usado.
El segundo problema es que la versión del SDK instalado no es compatible con la versión de tu proyecto, posiblemente tengas que actualizarlo. Te aconsejo usar un repositorio (Github, por ejemplo) para trabajar en un proyecto desde diferentes máquinas.

Comment: 1. Gracias por tu solucion, pero no lo guarde en Github, no existe otra solucion para este problema?
2. ¿Como lo actualizo? estoy algo perdido en android studio

Comment: No es una solución, por eso no es una respuesta... no estoy al día con Android

Comment: mmm ok. gracias de todas maneras

Comment: Se recomienda usar mismas versiones de android studio o una superior en la maquina de destino.

Answer (score 1):

En realidad son dos puntos el primero es el mostrado en el diálogo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El proyecto que intentas abrir tiene registrado una ruta del android SDK diferente a la que tienes en tu Android Studio con el cual tratas de abrir el proyecto. Probablemente era un proyecto creado en otra PC.

**Lo que tienes que realizar en este caso es aceptar y cambiará la configuración de la ruta del SDK a la que tienes en tu Android Studio.**

El segundo detalle

> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

**es necesario instalado JDK 1.8.** Puedes activar la opción "Use embedded JDK":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De hecho veo que usas Android Studio 1.5.1  con compileSDKVersion 25, te sugiero actualizar a la última versión de Android Studio.